# only allow new line in textarea

Tags: php, mysql, html, security, textarea

How do I add security to a textarea so the only thing that a user can enter (besides normal text) is a new line.

Example:

```
<textarea>
For some reason
I want this on 2 lines
</textarea>
```

Any other type of tags should not be allowed. I have done ALOT of tests with php security functions like htmlentities, strip_tags, nl2br, etc and I have not found anything that could do what I want. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I don't have any examples of how htmlentities did not work for me, because that is from past experience, but if someone can provide me with an example of how to use htmlentities to do this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is define a whitelist of allowable values which will include upper and lower alpha characters, line returns then anything else you want to allow (punctuation, numbers, etc.) A regular expression is easy enough to do this with and you'll need to validate the contents of the text area against this on submission.

Also, make sure you *always* run this on the server side. You can run it client side *as well* but you must make sure the mechanism can't be circumvented at the browser hence the server validation dependency.

Comment: A whitelist is definitely the best solution on the server-side, but a blacklist - if it's easier - could of course also be used on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the info! A whitelist would be perfect since I only want to allow <br> tags. How would I go about making a whitelist?

Comment: Andres - The reason blacklists are frowned upon is that it's very hard to catch every character you don't want to allow and they're very vulnerable to zero days i.e. exploits we don't yet know about. cbr0wn - I suggest you post another question for this (or see if one exists already). What you're asking for is a regular expression that only allows certain characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a matter of what are you going to do with "illegal" characters. If you want to simply cut them, you might find useful regular expressions. If you want to escape them, just use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only check input with php afterwards, because php is running on the server and not on the client-side. If you want to check it instantly you can make it with javascript, but it will be slowing down the input of the user.

Just trust the user and filter it afterwards, would be me suggestion.

HTH

Comment: "Just trust the user" is not normally seen in responses regarding security! No need to check it instantly with JS, just check it on form submission AND check it on the server.

Comment: Troy, you can also trust a user, by asking only two input to lines. It doesn't has to be a security issue. ... and of course, filtering is always on the server-side. Everything else is insecure and can be absolutely useless.

Comment: How exactly do I filter all tags except <br> ?